# I'm looking for a lib or any help to create grid(matrix) of points in pairs of 4(rectangle)

Tags: c#, geometry, grid

I need to get a library/algorithm or just write my own function where I give a start point and give the function parameters to draw out an array of rectangles(Rectangle object) in groups(unit object) of one or more. if you look at the example you can see rectangle 1 and 5 in a group(unit) and I want to be able to give a number of levels and a number of the rectangles in that level as well as width (width of rectangles in a unit will always be the same). all units on the same level are the same unit just copied
so the function would look something like this:

-->EXAMPLE [Grid Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC3Bu.jpg)

```
var Units ={
"Level_01" :[
                [A: 2500],
                [B: 590],
                [Width: 1200],
                [Numberof:4]
            ],
"Level_02" :[
                [A: 2500],
                [B:590],
                [Width: 1200],
                [Numberof:4]
            ]

}
DrawUnits(startpoint,Units)
```

I would appreciate any help I'm using c# if you can help in any other language you can. Thank You

PS I'm trying to do this using classes, Unit and rectangle class because I want to be able to add properties to the objects to work out area and quantities and more at a later stage.

Comment: But .. this example is too primitive to make some specific library. Just walk trough list of structures.

Comment: Agree that this example is primitive. I'm just looking for a start point so that I can build on it and expand.